# How to write just acronyms to a file

Tags: python

I was wondering how you could input a country from the user then write ONLY the acronyms to a file for example if the user entered United Kingdom then UK would be written in the file. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. But first, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an easy thing to implement without problems. What format does the input use, what convention does the output use, etc. 
This [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry-convert/) you can directly install with pip should provide appropriate functions.
If you want to implement this yourself, I would suggest normalising the input (spaces, caps), and using a dict.

```
countries = {'United Kingdom': 'UK', 'Spain': 'ES', ... }
```